# Error on line 2 at column 10: xmlParseDocTypeDecl : no DOCTYPE name

Tags: php, xml, mysqli

Just got this error, have no idea why, can anyone help?

> error on line 2 at column 10: xmlParseDocTypeDecl : no DOCTYPE name !

I am trying to take information from my database and output it into XML when I run it in the browser.
Here is my code

```
<?php 
  include 'header.php';

  function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
  { 
   $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
   $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
   $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
   $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
   $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
   return $xmlStr; 
  }

  // Select all the rows in the Blog table
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Blog WHERE 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
  if (!$result) 
  {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

  header("Content-type: text/xml");

  // Start XML file, echo parent node
  echo '<blog>';

  // Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
  while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
   // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
   echo '<blogs ';
   echo 'ID="' . parseToXML($row['ID']) . '" ';
   echo 'subject="' . parseToXML($row['subject']) . '" ';
   echo 'content="' . parseToXML($row['content']) . '" ';
   echo 'latitude="' . $row['latitude'] . '" ';
   echo 'longitude="' . $row['longitude'] . '" ';
   echo 'imageName="' . parseToXML($row['imageName']) . '" ';
   echo 'datetime="' . parseToXML($row['datetime']) . '" ';
   echo '/>';
 }

 // End XML file
  echo '</blog>';
?>
```

Comment: You are aware of the function [`htmlspecialchars`](http://pa1.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) that's built-in to PHP, right?  No reason to make your own `parseToXML` function.  P.S., *NEVER* use the `@` before a function call!  You should *ALWAYS* check for errors, not just ignore them.

Comment: Can you also show us the *generated* XML?  That might help more than the PHP code.  Also what is in `header.php`?  Does that echo anything?

Comment: header.php includes error checking and requires mysqli_connect.php file.  This works with my other pages so I wouldn't expect the error to be here.  There is no xml file, this code is to generate the xml from the data in the database.

Comment: I know there's no XML, I wanted to see the *generated* XML.  It would probably to see the error from the output of this script.

Comment: The XML isn't generated as the page renders to the first error which is said to be on line 2.  I can post the code for the included header and connection files if that would help?  I was following someones steps 'Using PHP's echo to Output XML' from an article [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#outputxml) The only thing I changed was the parent/child node names, database name, database content names and I changed it from mysql to mysqli to conform with my connection information file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out no DOCTYPE name literally means, I had not named my DOCTYPE.

I had

```
<!DOCTYPE>
```

Where I should have had

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Normally this would not cause a problem but since I was trying to output XML data everything has to be perfect in the Document Tree.